# Form confirmation with Razor, Url.Action

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, forms, razor

I can find many different ways to add confirmation to a form submission. The issue in my case is either they submit the form anyway or they just sit there and dont do anything. Any suggestions would be appreciated. I have added events to both the form onsubmit and the button onclick, no dice. The ActionResult in this case uses HttpPostRequest to send the form data. Works great, just want to add a confirmation dialogue that works.

```
<script>

function SubmitConfirm(){
    if (confirm("Are you sure want to submit this form?"))
        return true;
    else
        return false;     
}
```

```
  <form name="Form1" method="post" action="@Url.Action("PostForm", "MyController")"  id="Form1">
...

<input type="submit" value="Submit Posting" onclick="SubmitConfirm()" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to display that dialog without reloading the page, just when your submission is successful rather than taking them to a new page or implementing some sort of conditional refresh. So you could set up your form as such...

```
<form name="Form1" id="Form1">
    ...
     <input type="button" id="submit" value="Submit Posting" />
</form>
```

And using jQuery set up your actual submit thusly...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#submit').click(function() { submit(); });
});

function submit() {
    if (SubmitConfirm())
    {
        var data = $('#Form1').serialize();

        $.post('MyController/PostForm', data, function(result) {
             if (result === 'success') {
                 // just using an alert here as a placeholder
                 alert('Your submission has been received!');
             }
        });
    }
}
```

Which means that in your controller, you'll have the following...

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PostForm([form arguments])
{
    var success = // deal with form results, return true if everything is ok

    return new Content(success ? "success" : "failure");
}
```

To recap, you'd submit your form data, process it, and give the user feedback as to whether it was successfully processed or not without the user ever leaving the page, which also opens the door to make it easier to re-submit data if necessary and do validation, again without the user leaving the page or having to wait for the page to reload.

**EDIT**: Fixed typo and modified submission logic.

Comment: Thanx for the response. There is a small typo, (SubmitConfirm()) but there is also a "red line of death" under the open parenthesis in  "$('#Form1')." saying "Expected :". Not sure how to fix it.

Comment: @user116923, ok, updated the answer. For an example of how your content should be getting serialized, see http://jsfiddle.net/D2bA6/ and make sure you have a `name` attribute on all your fields. Basically the braces were unnecessary and just to avoid issues with `onclick` and `submit` I'm having you attach the submit button to a jQuery listener.